# Error While restoring DB2 db from AIX to AIX server?

Tags: db2, restore, migration

I am required to migrate 1 database  One AIX server to another AIX server. 
To achieve, I took backup from 1 machine and followed below steps

1st Command I tried is as  following.

```
db2 restore db DBNAME FROM /home/LOCATION taken at 20130912184605 into DBNAME1 REDIRECT generate script DBNAME1.sql
```

Which generated 1 sql file. Then I tired to run below command.

```
db2 -tvf DBNAME1.sql
```

I am getting following error

```
UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS USING S ON Z ON DBNAME_NODE0000.out V ON
DB21005E  An error occurred while accessing the file "DBNAME_NODE0000.out".
```

Answer (score 2):

`Z ON DBNAME_NODE0000.out` instructs the DB2 command line processor to redirect all output to a file named DBNAME_NODE0000.out in the current directory. Apparently, you don't have permissions to create files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems like this, just copy the number of the error and search for it in the [information center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp). In your case, it says

The following could have caused the error:

- file permissions do not allow file access
- the file does not exist

When it comes to file permissions in AIX, you need to make sure that users of type "others" can access the file.